# My Testnet Account has got few tokens other than EOS, which are not showing in Kylin Testnet wallet

Tags: tokens, wallet, testnet

Kylin test account: thomsonimjd15 has got few tokens like RTT, PPT, LVE
[image]

Please see the above image from explorere for transaction on the tokens

I have connected to the wallet using scatter, I am not able to view the tokens in token transfer

[image]

Please see the above image, there is no tokens like RTT, PPT  other than EOS.

Comment: This is probably an issue with the blok explorer you are using. Have you tried using a different explorer like bloks.io?

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's because you are using an extended token-contract which differs from the eosio.token-contract (has different/additional actions) and the explorer only shows tokens which match the common token-contract-structure.